# read and save a specific column from csv file

Tags: python, csv

need help! using previous topics, I found how I can read data form csv file and I do not have problem with this but I can not save a specific column (e.g. column 4 from file.csv) as new.csv file. my script prints column 4 correctly but it does not save it.

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    file1 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    fourth_col = []

    for cols in file1:
        fourth_col = cols[3]
        print (fourth_col)

        new_file = open('new.csv', 'w')
        writer = csv.writer(new_file)
        writer.writerows(fourth_col)
        new_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code and it is working fine

```
import csv

new_file = open('new.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(new_file)

with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    file1 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    fourth_col = []

for cols in file1:
    fourth_col = cols[3]
    print(fourth_col)
    writer.writerows(fourth_col)

new_file.flush()
new_file.close()
```

sample files:

file.csv

```
a,b,c,d,e
f,g,h,i,j
k,l,m,,n
,,,o,
```

new.csv

```
d
i
o
```

Comment: It works. thx! one more question: is there any way to write out new.csv as new. txt?

Comment: yes, you can, just change file name with extension.